# Fire a one-way ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF service which takes a long time to process the first time it is called, and then caches those results in `HttpRuntime.Cache`. In order to initialize this cache I'd like to trigger a fire-and-forget ajax call from javascript.

Right now I have this javascript in the page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: getServiceURL() + 'PrimeCacheAjax',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Where the `PrimeCacheAjax` function just performs a dummy call to populate the cache.

The only issue with this approach is that the page with this ajax call is a type of landing page which executes some javascript, opens another window and closes itself. When the window closes itself before the server responds, I see a cancelled request in fiddler. I am concerned that this may lead to situations where the ajax call may not reach the server, is this possible?

Is there a way to specify (using `$.ajax()`) that no response will be coming, or does it not really matter?

Comment: Just perform an `$.ajax` call with no callback, which is exactly what your code will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only time it will matter is if the request to the server is not complete. You should check to make sure the call is at a readyState value of 2 [aka sent], before exiting.

Comment: Waiting for `readyState==2` means waiting for the response headers from the server, which is *slightly* longer than the OP wants to wait, but I think this answer is the best possible solution available using the XHR API as it exists.

Comment: Any idea how ajax requests react to the server flushing the buffer? I've used that with an iframe before to get similar results where i flushed a <script></script to the iframe that would remove the iframe while the server-side script continued processing the request.

Comment: waiting for the readystate would probably be too long, if the user sees the launch page at all they will cry "DEFECT!". I guess we will just hope the request goes out - worst case scenario they wait a little longer for the cache to populate on their first hit.

Answer (score 0):

I would just perform a call with no callback, I don't believe there is a property that allows the F&F method.

for a very short ajax call you could try the following code as an alternative, if you wanted.

```
$.get('URL');
```